# Getting twitter user id from tweet id without json object

Tags: python, twitter

Currently I am working on twitter data. I need to fetch twitter data with the *tweet id* and *user id* of the tweet. Unfortunately, I am able to fetch the tweet with *tweet id* only. But along with that I want to get the *user id* too. I am fetching the tweets by giving the query of the search type. By working with individual *tweet id* I am able to get the username and from that username I can get the *user id*. But this manual work for each tweet is too lenghty. Can't there be a way to get directly the *user id* from the *tweet id*.

I am using python with tweepy library.

code for search with tweepy.

`public_tweets = api.search(q="TheGhantas", lang ="en", count = 200)`


`public_tweets.id_str`

is returning me the *tweet id* and this is helping me to get the tweet username. And from that username, I am getting the *user id*. 
Can there be a simple way to get directly the *user id* from *tweet ids* if I have a file with *tweet ids*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very simple.

You look up the Tweet using [`statuses/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid).  That will return the Tweet object as JSON.

Inside that JSON you will find the user object.

Here is a shortened example:

```
{
  "created_at": "Wed Jun 06 20:07:10 +0000 2012",
  "id_str": "210462857140252672",
  "text": "Along with our new #Twitterbird, we've also updated our Display Guidelines ^JC",
  "id": 210462857140252672,
  "user": {
    "name": "Twitter API",
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "statuses_count": 3333,
    "screen_name": "twitterapi"
  },
}
```

Depending on how you're getting the JSON, it's as simple as going `tweet->user->screen_name`

Comment: Currently I am not trying to implement it using JSON object. Using the search function I am getting the statuses directly. So is there any alternative other than this?